# Why can we assume surjectivity in short exact sequences?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, exact-sequence

This is brand new to me, so forgive me if this is simple.

I understand the structure of a short exact sequence (the image of the current homomorphism is the kernel of the next), and I can understand why $\phi$ is injective in the below example. What's confusing me is that everywhere says that $\psi$ is surjective, but I cannot see why. I've consulted some textbooks but can't find any material on it, and any online explanations don't help either.

$${0}\rightarrow N\xrightarrow{\phi} G\xrightarrow{\psi} Q\rightarrow 0$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\operatorname{im} \psi = \ker\lbrace Q \to 0 \rbrace = Q$ (by exactness!)

Comment: That makes perfect sense, and I can't believe I didn't spot it sooner. Post it as an answer so I can give you the reputation, it's the least I can do.

Answer (score 3):

By the definition the image of $\psi$ is the kernel of the next homomorphism, which is the zero morphism $Q\to 0$. And the kernel of the zero morphism is entire $Q$. And so $im(\psi)=ker(Q\to 0)=Q$ or in english: $\psi$ is surjective.